# Accessibility annoying issue with hidden UI Elements

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uiaccessibility

There is a table view and first cell in table view has a button. on touching the button, there 2nd cell which is hidden initially by setting the height as zero is slowly displayed (animation). This works awesome without any issues.

When i enable accessibility and make the accessibility label for the 2nd cell including its headerlabel, description label isaccessibility elements are set to no, there is no way they are actually hidden from accessibility's eyes. It still reads the content which is hidden in the background.

My question is how to avoid this issue ? i also set the accessibility label of the header and the description of the cell to @"", but it is not helping. Please give me a intuitive solution to solve this problem. Thanks

Comment: Are the child elements still accessible?

Comment: ya, i made it as NO but still accessible.

Comment: explicitly for subviews as well?